# . . skipping table while import in 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, datapump, impdp

When iam trying to import exp dump into 9i database its giving

```
imp ****/****@**** FULL=Y IGNORE=Y FILE=exp_****_4.dmp LOG=imp_****_4.log
export client uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SYSTEM's objects into ***
. importing OUTLN's objects into OUTLN
. importing PERFSTAT's objects into PERFSTAT
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered
ORA-01435: user does not exist

IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

And when i tried to look into dump with show=y option

```
imp ****/****@**** FULL=Y IGNORE=Y FILE=exp_****_4.dmp LOG=imp_****_4.log **SHOW=Y**
```

It has given me all the table and object list and scripts that dump is going to import but with **. . skipping table**

I not getting why this is happening..
There is no indication as to why these tables were skipped and there are many of them. 
I was able to load data into same DB from other dumps.

Comment: `ORA-01435: user does not exist`

Comment: it seem like table creation in another DB is like `create table user1.emp` and when you are trying to import on different DB you got error `user does not exist` as user1 is not present on DB where you are doing import operation. Suggection : Go for `IMPDP` as `IMP` is now older we have more facilities in `IMPDP`

Comment: `IMPDP USERNAME/PASSWORD@SID DUMPFILE= DUMP_FILE_NAME.dmp LOGFILE=IMP_NAGENDRA_LOG.LOG FULL=Y REMAP_SCHEMA=PREVIOUS_DB_USER:CURRENT_DB_USER ;`
For Example : `REMAP_SCHEMA=USER1:USER2 ;`

Comment: @Whiterabbit : check whether itsworking or not

Answer (score 1):

SHOW=Y instructs IMP not to import anything (to skip the import and just show you on the screen what's in the import file).